# Error installing npm package (dependency tree)

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying yo install the package react-lottie https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lottie

But I am getting this error, I want to know how to fix this, I know it has to do with dependancies but I struggle to find the answer.

**Error:**

[image]

**package.json**

```json
{
    "name": "laforga",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "laforga",
    "keywords": [
        "gatsby"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "develop": "gatsby develop",
        "start": "gatsby develop",
        "build": "gatsby build",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "gatsby": "^3.4.1",
        "gatsby-image": "^3.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^3.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^4.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^4.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.4.2",
        "gatsby-remark-lottie": "^1.0.3",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.4.0",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.4.0",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try again after running `npm install update`

Comment: Getting same error..

Comment: `npm rebuild` and then try again

Comment: also not working...

Comment: this package was last updated 3 years ago. could be outdated by now. This package seems more recent - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react

Comment: what version of node and npm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package you are using requires React v16 and you are using v17. To make it work you should be able to downgrade your version of React with `npm install react@16`.